# Angular Callback with arguments

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

```
 //Load Property Types
$scope.getAddressByPostcode = function() {
  PostCodeLookup.getAddress(function(postCodeAddress,'NN4 5DT') {
    $scope.postCodeAddress = postCodeAddress;
    console.log($scope.postCodeAddress);
  });
};
```

I have above code in my controller.
Below is what i have in my Angular Factory

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').factory('PostCodeLookup', ['$http', function($http) {
var apService = 'https://api.postcodes.io';

function getAddressByPostcode(callback,postcode) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apService+ '/postcodes/'+postcode,
        cache: true
    }).success(callback);
}
return {
    getAddress: getAddressByPostcode
};
}]);
```

i am having problem passing arguments to my getAddressByPostcode along with callback.

Does angular not handle callback with params.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code should be like this:

```
$scope.getAddressByPostcode = function() {
  PostCodeLookup.getAddress(function(postCodeAddress) {
    $scope.postCodeAddress = postCodeAddress;
    console.log($scope.postCodeAddress);
  },'NN4 5DT');
};
```

Notice the placement of the postal code parameter.

As @Martijn suggested, a better solution is to just return a promise from your factory function:

```
function getAddressByPostcode(postcode) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apService+ '/postcodes/'+postcode,
        cache: true
    });
}
return {
    getAddress: getAddressByPostcode
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
PostCodeLookup.getAddress('NN4 5DT').then(function(result) {             
    $scope.postCodeAddress = result.data;
    console.log($scope.postCodeAddress);
});
```

Comment: It would be nicer to return a promise and handle a .then in the controller instead of using a callback

Comment: Yes. I agree, let the caller decide how to handle success/error.

Comment: Yes thank you for reply, yes i can do that, but was just exploring if there is a way to do arguments with callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code snippets help to use callbacks with arguments:

Create a callback-object:

```
function createCallback(p_context, p_function, p_params) {

  if(angular.isFunction(p_function)) {
    var callback = {
      'context': p_context,
      'function': p_function,
      'params': p_params
    };

    return callback;
  } else {

    logger.error('createCallback(context, function, params): function not defined');
  }
}
```

execute callback:

```
function executeCallback(p_cb) {

  var callback = p_cb;

  cb['function'].call(cb['context'], cb['params']);
}
```

Wrapping it in a service, it is reusable...

Greets
Christian